# Añadir y eliminar elemento con addEventListener JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JS y estoy resolviendo unos ejercicios. Increíblemente realicé ejercicios más complejos pero no puedo resolver esto que llevo varios días queriendo solucionarlo. Básicamente necesito añadir un borde si clickeo y quitar el borde si vuelvo a clickear la imagen. Pude hacerlo con classList.toggle, pero no es el objetivo del estudio, así que me dí el trabajo de resolverlo con lo mencionado anteriormente. Si pulso la imagen, se añade el borde, pero no entiendo cómo hacer que sea a la inversa, o sea, que se quite. Les dejo el código que hasta ahora me ha resultado y si pudieran orientarme para saber más o menos cómo hallar la solución.

```
       <div class="flex_item_body">
        <figure>
            <img id="imagenId" class="imagen" src="./assets/img/road-1072823.jpg" alt="Bosque de Nueva Inglaterra">
        </figure>
        <figcaption>Clickea la imagen para añadir el borde. También, si clickeas, lo podrás quitar.</figcaption>
    </div>
```

Script externo

```
    const clickeado = document.querySelector("#imagenId");
clickeado.addEventListener('click', borde);
function borde(){
    if (clickeado){
    clickeado.style.border = "2px solid red"
}else{
clickeado.style.border = "none"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que te hace falta es una variable para conservar el estado del borde, si el borde no existe, es decir, es `false`, entonces agregarlo y si existe (Es `true`), entonces quitarlo.

Ejemplo:

```js
const clickeado = document.querySelector("#imagenId");

// Variable para conservar el estado del borde
let bordeVisible = false;

clickeado.addEventListener('click', borde);

function borde(){
    // Si el borde no es visible, es decir, es false
    if (!bordeVisible){
        // Se agrega el borde
        clickeado.style.border = "2px solid red"
    // Si el borde es visible, es decir, es true
    }else{
        // Se quita el borde
        clickeado.style.border = "none"
    }
    
    // Al ejecutar la función invertimos el booleano
    bordeVisible = !bordeVisible;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_item_body">
    <figure>
        <img id="imagenId" class="imagen" src="./assets/img/road-1072823.jpg" alt="Bosque de Nueva Inglaterra">
    </figure>
    <figcaption>Clickea la imagen para añadir el borde. También, si clickeas, lo podrás quitar.</figcaption>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que no entendía, cómo igualar la condicional if. Había pensado en algo como if(clickeado == true)... pero no se me había ocurrido investigar sobre los valores booleanos. Gracias por el dato. Le echaré un ojo.